# how can I validate an email in vueJs + firebase?

Tags: regex, validation, firebase, vue.js

how can I validate an email in vueJs + firebase?

for example I have data array email: ['badi@gmail.com','badEmail.com','realEmail.com']

and I usually validate it in vueJs+firebase like this

```
 computed: { 
 validation: function () {
  return {
    email: !!this.categoryTest.email.trim(),

  } 
},
isValid: function () {
  var validation = this.validation
  return Object.keys(validation).every(function (key) {
    return validation[key]
  })
},
}
```

but for checking array I'm
still confused..
thanks

Comment: Explain what your code should do, and what happens instead of it working please.

Comment: @Matthew Cliatt thanks, I have try following http://vuejs.org/examples/firebase.html but how I can validate email if in array for ex :['badi@gmail.com','badEmail.com','realEmail.com']

Comment: Did you look at the [examples in the API doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/string/matches.html), which show both how to validate an email and the reasons you probably shouldn't be doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: There is nothing special about VueJS and Firebase. You just need to use standard javascript.  See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript